# Rendering forms with django-semanticui-forms and confused with how choice fields work

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using the module django-semanticui-forms to render my forms in a nice format with SemanticUI. I'm confused about what they're doing with choice fields and how to use it in my own code.

```
CHOICES_1 = (
    (0, "Zero"),
    (1, "One"),
    (2, "Two"),
    (3, "Three"),
    (4, "Four"), 
    (5, "Five"),
)

class Choice(models.Model):
    choices_1_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES_1)
```

When I render the form, I'm able to choose between the six options and when I output the choice on a html form like {{user.choices_1_1}}, I get an integer. This makes sense because the model has an IntegerField here. How do I get the value associated with this integer key though? Is there an easy way to print "Zero" instead of 0 without casing on each integer and rendering the string that way?

Lmk if the question is confusing

Comment: Do you need to do that on html page or in post/pre processing in python?

Comment: that was sort of my question lol - the result shows up as an integer on the html page but I want it to be a string. I guess I'm confused on how/where to get the second value of the tuples in models.py, if possible

Comment: I mean if you already have an instance, you can use `{{ user.get_choices_1_1_display }}`